# How to create a WPF combobox flat style?

Tags: wpf, combobox, styles, controltemplate

I want to create a flat style template for WPF combobox which looks like a combobox in Visual Studio 2010. Also I want to use Visual Studio brushes for this template.

[image: Visial Studio 2010 combobox style]

Does anybody help me to find the way? Are there any completed templates? Also does anybody know something about an application that can get controls templates from other applications?

Answer (score 20):

Do you mean toolbar combobox toolbar style?
Try this

```
<ComboBox Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ComboBoxStyleKey}}"/>
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's a link to the standard combobox styles and templates:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094.aspx.

You should be able to add a style, similar to the following that makes the ComboBox flat (it may need some tweaking):

```
<Style x:Key="CustomComboBox"  TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="60"/>
    <Setter Property="UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />      
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

For checking over 3rd party .Net assemblies for control templates and styles, you can use [Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) (which now costs), or [Telerik's JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiling.aspx) (free). There are likely to be other tools similar to these, but these are all you need (especially Reflector).