# How can I style different items inside a combo box in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, devexpress

I have a combo box that display an item's Main category, Sub Category and Item. I'm having troubles trying to change their individual contents (I have a background in PHP and it's pretty easy to do it there as I can echo out html codes within php and just wrap the loop's output with bold but I'm not sure how to do it within c# and xaml).

Here's my code:

```
//For Main Category
SqlCommand get_maincategory_name = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM maincategory", sc);
SqlDataReader dr2 = get_maincategory_name.ExecuteReader();  
while (dr2.Read())
{
comboBox.Items.Add(dr2["maincategory_name"].ToString());

    //For Sub Category   
    int got_maincategory_id = Convert.ToInt32(dr2["maincategory_id"]);
    SqlCommand get_subcategory_name = new SqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT * FROM subcategory WHERE maincategory_id='{0}'", got_maincategory_id), sc);
    SqlDataReader dr3 = get_subcategory_name.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr3.Read())
    {
    comboBox.Items.Add("--" + dr3["subcategory_name"].ToString());

        //For Item
        int got_subcategory_id = Convert.ToInt32(dr3["subcategory_id"]);
        SqlCommand get_inventory_name = new SqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT * FROM item WHERE subcategory_id='{0}'", got_subcategory_id), sc);
        SqlDataReader dr4 = get_inventory_name.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr4.Read())
        {
        comboBox.Items.Add("----" + dr4["item_name"].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

What I kinda wanted to happen was:

1. To bold the main category items and probably change its font to 2 more
   pts compared to the sub category and inventory
2. To apply a left margin within the sub category's text and the combo box (it looks like the sub category's items has four spaces before it)
3. To apply the same left margin with the inventory but with eight spaces before it

(I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and have devexpress if that helps)

Comment: You need to create brushes in wpf and set style accordingly. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/brushes-in-wpf/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241540/how-to-create-a-wpf-combobox-flat-style

Comment: How will xaml know which specific contents to modify? Because the only bold ones would be the main category items, the only 4 left margin would be the sub category items and the only 8 left margin would be the items.

Comment: You need to apply that styling dynamically in C# code.

Comment: Yeah I figured although I don't know what C# code can tell xaml to modify its contents. I'll try asking the devexpress support on what are my options.

Comment: Define the `ItemTemplate` of combo box item. In data template of overridden item teamplate, you can put data trigger to style your item appropriately.

Comment: Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it is impossible to provide specific suggestions for your own scenario. Likely, your question is a duplicate of several other Stack Overflow questions anyway. Without more specifics, it's not possible to know exactly which is the most appropriate though.

Comment: To change visual appearance based on _values_ in your data, you can bind visual properties to those values, using an `IValueConverter` to map the value to the appropriate visual state. To do so based on the _type_ of your data objects, you can declare a different `DataTemplate` for each type in question. In most cases, very little C# code will be required, if any (i.e. at most, an `IValueConverter` object).